# how to add to the media library in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, media

I'm a beginning programmer, so sorry if this sounds stupid. I understand that I have to put the image into Xcode through the media library... but where is the media library? I threw the image file into the folder I made when I created the project but it's not showing up. I have the same image in there in 2 formats: PNG and JPEG. Where is the location of the "Media Library"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do you mean with Media Library? The pane in Interface Builder on the bottom right? That just lists all the media items that are part of your current project or workspace.

You have to add the images to your project, if you want to use them in your app. The easiest way is to drag them in one of the Groups in Xcode's Project Navigator tab on the left side. Make sure you check your target (this will make Xcode copy the images into your app's resources on compile time).

Comment: OMG thank you so much!!! You have no idea how long I've been messing around with this. Sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: This answer is correct, however in my case I added some images which did not show up in the "Media Library" in Interface Builder until I restarted XCode. If they aren't showing up, try restarting :)

Comment: You can add image file on Assets.xcassets folder by drag and drop and can access it from Media Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the png or jpg, first, you need to create an imageset and then restart xcode, it would be available inside the media library.
To create an image set, you need to select the Assets.xcassets in the left navigation pane, and then in the tool bar select the editor -> Add Assets -> New Image Set. Give a name to your image and select render as Template Image.